# Kivy freezes on increasing window size

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, raspberry-pi3, kivy-language

I have developed a kivy program and I am running it on raspberry pi. The program works amazingly on Windows but on raspberry pi I am having a problem. The program works properly for small window size but when I maximize the window size or increase the size of the window the entire raspberry pi freezes and nothing works . I have to turn of the main switch so I can boot again. Also I have downloaded some background images from the net to use in the kivy program but some of them work while for others a black screen appears with the buttons on it. I don't understand what's causing this.

My suspects:-

1. I suspect it has got something to do with gpu ram but I have assigned 512 mb ram to it already which I think should be more than enough.
2. I have read about the screen manager and slide transition issues of kivy in raspberry pi but I don't think that they are the cause of this cause they work when the window size is small enough also except for the background image problem

3) I have also installed zram module on my pi. Could that be any reason for all of this??[zram module link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/novaspirit/rpi_zram&ved=2ahUKEwjlg7H9m6HfAhULb30KHWTmDOIQFjAKegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw1lPDWXQsXXyfGlcArxSj4a)

Any suggestions?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The program works properly for small window size but when I maximize the window size or increase the size of the window the entire raspberry pi freezes and nothing works

What window provider are you using, sdl2 or the rpi-specific one?

> Also I have downloaded some background images from the net to use in the kivy program but some of them work while for others a black screen appears with the buttons on it

You get the black rectangle if the image is larger than can fit within a single GPU Texture. Kivy doesn't have a way to automatically work around that, although it's possible. The simplest solution is to use smaller images.

Comment: I just checked. I am using sd12 window provider